# ionic cant get network connection consistently - when building for ios/android platform

Tags: ios, cordova, networking, ionic-framework

I just cant consistently get a network connection for my ionic app on my ios device. It works sometimes with the reset, remove&add platforms but recently it just doesnt work. Im trying it over 10 times already. Its crazy.

How do i get network working consistently on ionic ? (cordova-plugin-network-information)

Im using ionic version 1.7.14

I'ved tried several ways like

```
ionic state reset
```

or

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios
```

I'ved got this error:

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.connection.type')
```

in my config.xml, here are my plugins.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-image-picker" spec="https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="com.raananw.imageResizer" spec="https://github.com/RaananW/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer" />    
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.1.1" />    
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-actionsheet" spec="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git" />
<plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="~1.12.5" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using event listener by the same plugin

Comment: this is how i do it https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67d7f3c79590d57d055837dd21b1a7c8

Comment: are you saying like this https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/60 ? how can i have non async for checking offline  ?